# Google Play, Samsung apps & Amazon: how to change free app as paid

Tags: android, ios, coronasdk

We've uploaded an app on all major store & kept free now we want to make that app as paid app, how to do that, do we need to upload new version and change to paid, or we can directly change edit it please help us.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and this is not a programming question. It is a sales and marketing question.

Comment: App developer come here who might had done this several times so I asked here.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a programming question, but I'll help you out regardless.

You will need to upload a new version of your app, and put that one as paid. 
You cannot change a free app into a paid one, but you can turn a paid app into a free one. You agreed to this the first time you published your app.

> Please note that once you have published an application for free, you
>   cannot later add a price to that app. You'll need to create new app
>   and add a price to the new app.

Source: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138412?hl=en

Comment: you mean I need to update that app with e.g. 1.1 & set it as 2$???

Comment: No, not update, actually publish it as a new application. So that means a new APK, with a new packagename, etc. A completely new app.